# why does this regular expression always return null?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I need to check for classname in a string.

My string looks like this:

```
testing ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-f ui-first-child ui-filter-hidequeue
```

And I'm looking for `ui-filter-hidequeue` anywhere (!) in the string.

This is what I'm trying. It always returns `null`, althought the string I'm trying to match is there:

```
var classPassed = 'ui-filter-hidequeue',
    classes = 'testing ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-f ui-first-child ui-filter-hidequeue',
    c = new RegExp('(?:\s|^)' + classPassed + '(?:\s|$)');

console.log( classes.match(c) )   // returns null
```

**Question:**
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my regex?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get the string from? If these are the classes for an element, jQuery lets you test class membership directly, I think.

Comment: `$('#selector').hasClass('ui-filter-hidequeue')`

Comment: @Thilo: element.className. So via Javascript

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: yes. jQuery is easy, but I'm trying in pure Javascript.

Comment: @Thilo. Oh sorry. You can mark as duplicate then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\\s`. `\s` inside a string would escape the `s`, which does not need escaping, and evaluates to just a `"s"`. I.e. when you're using literal regexps, backslash escapes the regexp characters; and strings also use backslash to escape string characters. When you build a regexp from a string, you need to think about both of these layers: `\\` is string-escapey way of saying `\`, then `\s` is the regexp-escapey way of saying whitespace.

Also as other comments show, there are WAY better ways to test for class presence. :) But I just answered the direct error.

Comment: ok. Still curious on "way better".

Comment: @frequent: I think you got it, with Thilo's comment above. Regexp is an overkill, besides being unreliable for non-controlled input.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
c = new RegExp('\\b' + classPassed + '\\b');
```

The `\b` metacharacter matches at the beginning/end of a word; it stands for boundary (as in, word boudnary).

Comment: `\b` is not appropriate, as it will also match at the boundary between the minus sign and a word.

Comment: @Amadan, ah, good point, I sometimes forget about the minus signs being part of a 'word' in HTML classes etc